# Show heat map on map view by taking set of coordinates of map view using heatma.ps

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, heatmap

In my iOS application, I have a map view and I showed some annotations by taking set of coordinates. Now, I want to show heat map for these set of coordinates. I installed heatma.ps for displaying heat map. But I'm not getting how to use this framework to display heat map. Please tell me how to display heat map using heatma.ps.....

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 0):

Heatma.ps is an analytics tools. You can't use it to get a heat map based on the coordinates.

Heatma.ps collects user touches and generates touch heat maps so you can understand which areas of the screen your users touch the most.

To do what you want you would have to implement heat maps yourself.